# Robot Framework: Using current date in the variable is not working

Tags: robotframework

My Variables header inside my Robot file looks like:

```
*** Variables ***
${date} =  Get Current Date    result_format=%Y%m%d%H%M%S
${workspaceName} =  Workspace${date}
```

When I use `${workspaceName}` later in the file, it's content is "Get Current Date    result_format=%Y%m%d%H%M%S" as a string. But when `${workspaceName}` is defined inside a test case, it works correctly.

Is it true that the Variables section can't contain functions? For example `Get Current Date`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. You cannot call functions within the `***Variables***` section.
If you would like to use the `Get Current Date` Function and assign it to a Variable you will need to do it within the `***Test Cases***` section or the `***Keywords***` section!

For example:

```
***Settings***
Library    DateTime

***Variables***
[...]

***Test Cases***
[...]
${CurrentDate} =    Get Current Date    result_format=%Y%m%d%H%M%S
Log    ${CurrentDate}

***Keywords***
[...]
# Can do it here too!
```

Will log today's date in the format you have specified.
Hope this helps! Any other questions please ask away!